# In Objective-C how do you mark a critical region?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I have a simple scenario where a `NSTimer` is scheduled on a background thread to send a packet through a socket every so often. My main thread however, is responsible for destroying the timer and the socket.

The destruction looks like this:

```
if (self.connected) {
    [self.pingTimer invalidate];

    if (self.socket != -1) {
        close(self.socket);
        self.socket = -1;
    }

    self.connected = NO;
}
```

How can I ensure in Objective-C that once this section of code is entered, the scheduler isn't allowed to suspend this thread until the code section is over? In other words I want to make this code section atomic.

My understanding is that the `@synchronized` directive is a high-level semaphore/mutex so to ensure atomicity of that code block, I would need to enclose the code block itself, as well as all the code which references either `self.connected`, `self.pingTimer` and `self.socket` in `@synchronized` directives. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: @synchronized is a semaphore, which is to say that if you have two threads that synchronize *on the same object*, only one can have the semaphore at a time.  So it protects not only the region it surrounds but also anything called from that region.  To my knowledge, there's no way (at the Objective-C level) to implement a "critical region" where dispatching cannot occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to prevent the OS from preempting your thread and have another run in its place. The best you can do is synchronize the access. But in reading your code I infer the following:

- connected is an internal state variable.
- You want to avoid the timer being scheduled while your are disconnecting.
- You want to avoid disconnecting while the timer is scheduled.

I think its best to avoid synchronization whenever possible. Fortunately, you are using a NSTimer, which will make things trivial.

NSTimer does NOT run on a background thread but on a NSRunLoop and *probably* on the main run loop just like your `dealloc`. Timers are event sources for the run loop. When they fire they enqueue an event, which in turn calls your code when it gets processed. Because run loops process one event at a time it means that the code in your scheduled timer and the code in your dealloc get fully executed before the other can run. It also means that you don't need any special synchronization mechanism.

```
- (void) dealloc
{
   // ...
   if (_connected) {
       [_pingTimer invalidate];
       if (_socket != -1)
           close(_socket);
   }
   // ...
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Note: I prefer to use the state variables directly when I can unless the setters have other side effects. There is also no point in setting state variables in dealloc simply because the object will disapear once the method call is done.

Answer (score 3):

`@synchronized` is one way. Another would be to use `NSLock` or `NSRecursiveLock`. You can even use plain POSIX pthread locking primitives. See the [Multithreading Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1).

```
@interface Stuff 
{
    NSLock* lock;
    int cell;
}

- (int) cellValue;
- (void) someOperation;

@end

@implementation Stuff

- (id) init  
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
        cell = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (int) cellValue 
{
    [lock lock];
    @try
    {
        return cell;
    }
    @finally 
    {
        [lock unlock];
    }
}

- (void) someOperation 
{
    [lock lock];
    @try
    {
        // Do something involving access to stuff protected by
        // the lock (only cell here, but could be more, of course)
    }
    @finally 
    {
        [lock unlock];
    }
}

@end
```

Using `@synchronized`, the code above would look simpler:

```
- (int) cellValue 
{
    @synchronized (self)
    {
        return cell;
    }
}
```